# How to strip background color when using html5 canvas image?

Tags: image, html, canvas, background-color

If canvas can strip background color from a external image which is loaded(drawimage) into this canvas?

I think canvas can manipulate pixels, so it should strip the image background color.
After some searching, I still can't find a answer or any idea for it.

Answer (score 1):

in **[a demo I wrote](http://1.618033988.com/1/)** (personal spam ;) there is something you could need:

the [full source](http://1.618033988.com/1/js/canvas.js) is here

- first it reads an image

  ```
  brush.load({
  imageUrl: "brush-2.png",
  onload: function (brush) { 
      setBG(brush);
  }
  ```

  });
- then it manipulates the pixels

  ```
  for(p = 0; p < l; p = p + 4){
    r = pixels.data[p + 0];
    g = pixels.data[p + 1];
    b = pixels.data[p + 2];
    a = pixels.data[p + 3];

    pixels.data[p + 0] = k;
    pixels.data[p + 1] = m;
    pixels.data[p + 2] = o;
    pixels.data[p + 3] = a;
  ```

  }
- then it sets the image from the imageData

  ```
  document.body.style.backgroundImage= "url(" + ctx.canvas.toDataURL() + ")";
  ```

[more here](http://1.618033988.com/)

Comment: great! Learn very much from your website.Thank you!